# Grab data saved in Firebase and present it on view controller

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Edit (I hope this is more specific):

I can't seem to get the data from firebase to show up the page when i run the app:

When a notification is saved under a child node on firebase, an 'objectId' is printed - I want to grab the data under the node that matches this objectId under another node called 'pinion', a snippet of the JSON firebase structure is:

```
"notification" : {
    "Gmg1ojNoBiedFPRNSL4sBZz2gSx2" : {
      "-L_xNVcs7f3RhuLAcg7j" : {
        "from" : "Gmg1ojNoBiedFPRNSL4sBZz2gSx2",
        "objectId" : "-L_xNVcfZavjGFVv6iGs",
        "timestamp" : 1552586771,
        "type" : "pinion"
      },
"pinions" : {
    "Gmg1ojNoBiedFPRNSL4sBZz2gSx2" : {
      "-L_xNVcfZavjGFVv6iGs" : {
        "option A" : "Aaaa",
        "option B" : "Cccc",
        "question" : "Four",
        "selectedId" : "FoFQDAGGX9hntBiBdXYCBHd8yas2",
        "uid" : "Gmg1ojNoBiedFPRNSL4sBZz2gSx2"
      },
  "users" : {
    "Gmg1ojNoBiedFPRNSL4sBZz2gSx2" : {
      "email" : "eeee@gmail.com",
      "fullname" : "Eeee",
      "profileImageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pinion-4896b.appspot.com/o/profile_image%2FGmg1ojNoBiedFPRNSL4sBZz2gSx2?alt=media&token=209e57ca-b914-4023-8f85-fadfae7b7407",
    },
```

Would appreciate any help and let me know if you need any other information - thank you in advance :)

UPDATE:

It's working for the question and answers but I am getting an error "Unable to infer closure type in the current context" when calling the image:

```
@IBOutlet weak var senderProfileImage: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    showImageOfSender()
}
var ref = Database.database().reference()
var userId = "" //this was made equal to the autoId under pinion, under the users ID in another view controller

 func showImageOfSender() {
    var senderPhoto = [String]()
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
        return
    }

   let senderId = ref.child("pinions").child(uid).child(userId).child("uid")
        ref.child("users").child(senderId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
 //error is in the above line
        let senderImage = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "profileImageUrl").value as! String
        senderPhoto.append(senderImage)

        let senderImageUrl = URL.init(string: senderImage)
        self.senderProfileImage.sd_setImage(with: senderImageUrl)
    })
}
```

Comment: _how to_ questions on SO are always badly received, your code above demonstrates nothing about your question. You need to show us the actual approach to the intended feature, not any part of your UI

Comment: Okk sure - i've broken the question down a little more and edited the title so hopefully it makes more sense now :)

Comment: Your question is essentially asking *How do I read data from Firebase* which is thoroughly covered in the Getting Started Guide [Read & Write Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write). Can you include the code you're using to read that data? Once we see where you're stuck, we may be able to help.

Comment: @edey your `userID` is `""` so when you do `let uid = userId` and use it in the observer that would make it crash as you never told it what the UID is.

Comment: so when you look for the `pinionID` its crashing because it is looking not at `.child(uid)` but `.child("")` which doesnt exist.

Comment: Oh yes thanks - i made the userId equal to the pinionId that i want to call but there is still a problem calling the image - I’ve updated it in the code, hopefully it’s clear :)

Comment: @edey I think you are not getting the `senderId` correctly

Comment: @edey as you would need an event observer on `let senderId = ref.child("pinions").child(uid).child(userId).child("uid")` also

Comment: to get the value out as `string` etc. at the moment that line is probably returning nothing

Comment: Oh yes it worked, thank you!

Comment: @edey awesome! No problem! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you mean, first import Firebase:

```
  import Firebase
```

then get the database reference:

```
  class PinionNotificationsViewController: UIViewController {

   var ref: DatabaseReference!

   ...

   }
```

then your function can look like this if you know the UID:

```
func showQuestionAndAnswers() {

let uid = userId
ref = ref.child("pinions").child(uid)

ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        // Get user value
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let optionA = value?["option A"] as! String
        let optionB = value?["option B"] as! String
        print(optionA) // <- prints: "Bbbb"
        print(optionB) // <- prints: "Dddd"

    })
 }
```

If you don't know the uid you can use

```
ref = ref.child("pinions")
ref.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        // Get user value
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let optionA = value?["option A"] as! String
        // then you can append these values into an array it will go through all of them eg:
         self.answersArray.append(optionA) // answers array will contain all optionA values from all children in the database under `"pinions"`

    }
```

This way in my experience would match the database order so in your array all options would be in the order of their children as they are in the database.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! I've tried this but am still getting some errors - I have updated everything in my question to make it more specific, hope its more clear

Comment: Which line does it give the error at?